# Could not load file or assembly in Crystal Reports SP 21 for VS 2017

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, crystal-reports

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm getting this error in Visual Studio 2017 Crystal Reports SP 21 any solution?

Comment: did you install crystal reports plugin?

Comment: sorry which plugin ?